# fromROSMsg saves an unstructured pointcloud?

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When retrieving pointclouds from kinect openni (topic: /camera/rgb/points) and calling

```
pcl::fromROSMsg(*pcl2_msg_, pcl_xyzrgb_);
```

the pointcloud goes from structured tu unstructured.

```
ROS_INFO("msg size %d %d size %d %d ",pcl2_msg_->height, pcl2_msg_->width, (int) pcl_xyzrgb_.height, (int)pcl_xyzrgb_.width);
```

outputs

```
[ INFO] [1328803389.512748025]: msg size 480 640 size 1 101595 
[ INFO] [1328803389.945569604]: msg size 480 640 size 1 101593 
[ INFO] [1328803390.400027375]: msg size 480 640 size 1 101676 
[ INFO] [1328803390.840122150]: msg size 480 640 size 1 101569
```

and so on.

Any hint why this happens and how to keep the pointcloud dense and structured?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12959/fromrosmsg-saves-an-unstructured-pointcloud?/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2012-02-10**:
I had diagnosed the problem wrong, it's not fromROSMsg that unstructures the point cloud but removePlanes and copyPointCloud when going from xyz to rgb.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-09**:
I've used fromROSMsg and maintained the dense pointcloud structure. Are you running it through any of the nodelet filters first? Those tend to output unstructured clouds. How are you initializing pcl_xyzrgb_?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
But how do you decide that its unstructured cloud. 480x640 mentions that its structured. when u have it as 1x307200 then it is unstructured. So i guess its fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it's the extract.filter that unstructures the pointcloud, which I guess is the intended behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) with karma: 169 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0